# Unable to boot after removing disk

Tags: boot, disk-management

Since I removed disk 2 I'm unable to boot.

I get “Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key.”

I cleaned up my BIOS. There is only one BOOT device enable: disk 0

How can I solve this problem?

[image: Disk setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disk 2 contains your active partition. This is the partition that the computer needs to boot from. - Either put the disk back, or use a Windows (i am assuming you are using windows) installation disk to boot into 'Repair my computer'. One of the options will ask to fix your computer automatically - This works for most boot issues.

Comment: The disk is already back in. Is there a way I can move the boot sector from one disk to another. (Disk 2 is an old disk ready for replacement)

Comment: There's no simple way to replace this disk as it has the hidden system partiton, and is also the boot and active partitions. Safest and easiest is to remove all disks. Install new disk. Reinstall Windows then copy the stuff you need from the other disk. You could also try using macrium reflect to create an image of the system as it is currently, then restore to the new disk with help from the macrium CD boot image that you can create within macrium.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this is Windows?
Have you tried selecting the boot options during start-up and viewing the options are available to you? This is normally done by pressing the **DEL** or **F12** key during start-up.

You could also try seeing if safe mode is available to you by pressing F8 during start-up.